# AJAX Post not sending the correct values

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am trying to send data from my view to my controller using AJAX.  Once that is done, the idea is to forward that data to a new view, which will then use it to display information accordingly.  However, when I try it, the data does not reach the view.  What is weird, is that in using Chrome's Developer Tools, if I console_log the data in the success function of the AJAX call, it shows the variable being correct, but when I just try to display that variable in html, it has a value of 0.  Any ideas?

My view function:

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e){
    guess = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
    if (counter < test_key.length){
      if (guess == 'f' || guess == 'j'){
        if (guess == test_key[counter].answer){
            console.log(counter);
            console.log(test_key[counter]);
            $(document).off('keyup');
            $('#imageLocation').hide();
            counter++;
            practiceTask(counter, test_key, test_id); 
          }
        else{
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo site_url('practiceTest/errorPage'); ?>',
            data: {question: 6},
            success: function(data){
              console.log(data);
              window.location.href = '<?php echo site_url('practiceTest/errorPage'); ?>';
            } 
          }); 
        } 
      }  
    }
});
```

My Controller errorPage function:

```
function errorPage(){
    if (!empty($_POST['question'])){
        $data['question'] = $this->input->post('question');
    }
    else{ 
        $data['question'] = 0;
    }
    $this->load->view("practice_incorrect_view", $data);
}
```

And my new view practice_incorrect_view:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>    
     <?php echo $question; ?> 

     <div class="centered">
       <div style="width: 500px; margin: 20px auto;">
       </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're PHP is not returning anything that can be output. What is calling `errorPage()` when the script receives input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you are POSTing to `practiceTest/errorPage` successfully (hence correct console), but in your success callback, you are navigating to `practiceTest/errorPage` which doesn't know anything about the form data you just POSTed.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo site_url('practiceTest/errorPage'); ?>',
    data: {question: 6},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        //-- this is the troublesome line
        //-- window.location.href = '<?php echo site_url('practiceTest/errorPage'); ?>';
    } 
});
```

You should be modifying the DOM directly using the data returned from the successful AJAX request instead of redirecting using `window.location`.

Is there an example somewhere?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance on this, as I am just now learning CodeIgniter, but how else can I reroute to the practice_incorrect_view view after ajax call?

Comment: You would probably setup a form with practiceTest/errorPage as the action and have your keyup event submit() instead of ajax(). Hard to say without a live example.